# I wanted to display numbers as alphanumberics

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose in table I have a number column as

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want to display those rows as

```
one
two
three
four
```

How can I do using SQL

Comment: I apologize for miscommunication, All the data present in one column that empid column, so I need display all the data in empid column as alphabets

Answer (score 2):

You can use a technique from [this blog](http://briankoser.com/blog/oracle-numbers-to-english/) which uses a hack with dates to get the text version of numeric fields. The blog post goes into much more detail, but in short, it converts the number to a Julian date which lets `TO_CHAR` use the format specifier `sp` (spelling out in text)

```
SELECT num, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(num, 'J'), 'Jsp') num_as_text 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY num;

# num  num_as_text
# ----------------
# 1    One
# 2    Two
# 3    Three
# 4    Four
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joachim Isaksson this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `j --> jsp` technique to **spell the number**. It's been a [FAQ](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:18305103094123).

- **j = julian**.  take the number and pretend it is a julian date, convert 
  it into a date.
- **jsp** = Take that date and spell the julian number it represents.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT LEVEL,
  2         to_char(to_date(LEVEL,'j'), 'jsp') num_spell
  3  FROM dual
  4  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

     LEVEL NUM_SPELL
---------- ----------
         1 one
         2 two
         3 three
         4 four
         5 five
         6 six
         7 seven
         8 eight
         9 nine
        10 ten

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Excellent Lalit, it shows the output exactly how I want, I lost a interview bcz of this question, Thanks to you.

Comment: @sivakrishna All the best for your future interviews :-) Please mark it as answered, would help others too!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the schema is structured as you suggest like:

```
Table 
1     2     3     4
value value value value
value value value value
value value value value
```

You can use `AS` to rename the column in a query:

```
SELECT 1 AS one
       2 AS two
       3 AS three
       4 AS four
FROM table
```